# Swagger Gen V3 Not Resolving Internal $ref And Instead has Insane broken Import

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am generating via a yaml file

```
apply plugin: 'java'

import io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator
import io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator

def swaggerInput = "${rootDir}/BundledExports/API/POMOrchestrator.v1-Bundled.json"
def templatedir = "${rootDir}/templates".toString()
def swaggerOutputDir = file('application/')

task generateApi {
    inputs.file(swaggerInput)
    outputs.dir(swaggerOutputDir)
    doLast {
        def config = new CodegenConfigurator()
        config.setInputSpec(swaggerInput)
        config.setOutputDir(swaggerOutputDir.path)
        config.setIgnoreFileOverride(swaggerOutputDir.path)
        config.setLang('spring')
        config.setAdditionalProperties([
                'modelPackage'   : 'com.models.swagger',
                'modelNamePrefix': 'Party',
                'dateLibrary'    : 'java8',
                "fullJavaUtil"   : true,
                "library"        : "spring-boot",
                'templateDir'    : templatedir,
                'interfaceOnly'  : 'true'   // Generating the Controller API interface and the models only

        ])
        config.setImportMappings([
                'hello': 'com.models.Hello'
        ])
        new DefaultGenerator().opts(config.toClientOptInput()).generate()
    }
}

clean.doFirst {
    delete(swaggerOutputDir)
}

configurations {
    swagger
}

sourceSets {
    swagger {
        compileClasspath = configurations.swaggerCompile
    }
}

compileSwaggerJava.dependsOn generateApi
classes.dependsOn swaggerClasses
compileJava.dependsOn compileSwaggerJava

ext {
    swaggerVersion = '3.0.20'
    SwaggerGenerators = '1.0.20'
}

dependencies {

    compile sourceSets.swagger.output
    compile "io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen:$swaggerVersion"
    compile "io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-generators:$SwaggerGenerators"

}
```

And I have a very large json file.  I am unable to share the whole thing.  But here is the problem.  Internal $ref on this line:

```
                                        "op": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/OnboardingRequest/properties/customers/items/properties/controlPersons/items/properties/op"
                                        }
```

And here is the definition in the correct path

```
                                        "op": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "title": "FieldOperation",
                                            "enum": [
                                                "ADD",
                                                "UPDATE",
                                                "REMOVE"
                                            ]
                                        }
```

When I generate, here is what I get:

```
...
import com.models.swagger.PartyOnboardingRequestpropertiescustomersitemspropertiescontrolPersonsitemspropertiesop;
...

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PartyInvestmentExperience   {

  ...

  @JsonProperty("op")
  private PartyOnboardingRequestpropertiescustomersitemspropertiescontrolPersonsitemspropertiesop op;

  ...
```

Which does not compile because there is no class with that huge name.  I have been searching all over the internet and have not been able to find how to make this resolve.  I was wondering if maybe it is too deep being like 10 levels but there are other references deeper that get resolved correctly.  SO I am at a loss as to how to fix this.

Also, I have had the json validated and it had not errors.

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: @Helen I would but at work github is view only.  I can't log in or even download from is.